# Is it possible for a simulink block to notify the user if a fixed-step solver is being used?

Tags: matlab, simulink, solver

I developed a block which behaves incorrectly if the user chooses a fixed-step solver.

Is it possible for the block to check which solver is being used, and notify the user if a fixed-step solver is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short version

This is definitely possible! You can use the callback-function `StartFcn` in the model properties (or in the block itself). This function is being executed each time the model is being simulated. Then add a check for the solver-type that throws an error if it is set to `Fixed-step`.

Here is the code to add:

```
if(strcmp('Fixed-step',get_param(bdroot,'SolverType')))
error('Do not use a fixed-step solver because the results are not correct!');
end
```

This throws the following error in the Diagnostic Viewer when your model's name is `test`:

[image: error]

#### Detailed explanation of the code

We get the name of the top-level Simulink system by executing `bdroot` . This system name is then used for the call to get the solver-type with `get_param(bdroot,'SolverType')`. Then we use `strcmp` to compare the returned string with `'Fixed-step'`. If the current solver is fixed-step then `strcmp` returns `1`, so we enter the if-statement and throw the error with the `error`-function.

#### Add it to a block

To add the callback-function to a block, right-click the block, then on *Properties* as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: step1_block]

And then go to *Callbacks -> StartFcn* and paste the code:

[image: step2_block]

#### Add it to a model

To add the callback-function to the model click on *Model Properties* as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: step1_model]

And then go to *Callbacks -> StartFcn* and paste the code:

[image: step2_model]

That's it. I hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort Matt. Your answer was very helpful and solved my problem. However, I'd like to point out that the behavior I was intending is for the block itself to check the solver. If I understood your answer correctly, you provided a way for the model to check it; therefore, it would be up for the users of my block to specify that in their models, correct?

Comment: I was able to obtain the behavior I was looking for by putting the code you provided in my block's Initialization pane (in its mask).

Comment: @JLagana: Right-click the desired block, click `Properties`. Go to the tab `Callbacks` and add it to the desired callback-function. `StartFcn` for example.

Comment: That's even better. Thank you again.

Comment: Helpful and thorough. Thanks again.

Comment: I just realized that this approach doesn't work as intended if the block is placed inside a subsystem. When I do so, I get the following error: "SubSystem block does not have a parameter named 'SolverType'". Any suggestions?

Comment: :I managed to solve the above problem using `strcmp('Fixed-step',get_param(bdroot,'SolverType'))`, instead of `strcmp('Fixed-step',get_param(get_param(0,'CurrentSystem'),'SolverType'))`. Please consider updating your answer if this is correct.

Comment: @JLagana Thanks for the remark... I just updated the answer and changed the addressing to `bdroot`. Very elegant solution!